# c++ can use chromium base::callback in interface?

Tags: c++, callback, chromium

can i use chromium `base::callback` in interface?
i will put the callback to another Dynamic Link Library threadpools but i'm not sure it is right and which module 
release the callback?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, you can. From documentation

> // The Callback objects themselves should be passed by const-reference, and
>   // stored by copy. They internally store their state via a refcounted class
>   // and thus do not need to be deleted.
>   //
>   // The reason to pass via a const-reference is to avoid unnecessary
>   // AddRef/Release pairs to the internal state.

[Link to documentation.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/base/callback.h&l=39)